# not getting expected output?

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

n,m =list(map(int,input().split()))
if n == m:
   print('yo')
   print(np.identity(n))
if n > m:
   x = np.identity(m)
   arr = np.vstack((x,np.zeros((n-m,m))))
   print(arr)

if n < m:
   x = np.identity(n)
   arr = np.hstack((x,np.zeros((m-n,m))))
   print(arr)
```

above works for n=m but fails for the other two.
I wanted it to print array.
even if I use life it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in line 15. You should change it to:

```
arr = np.hstack((x,np.zeros((n,m-n))))
```

So your code becomes:

```
import numpy as np

n,m =list(map(int,input().split()))
if n == m:
   print('yo')
   print(np.identity(n))
if n > m:
   x = np.identity(m)
   arr = np.vstack((x,np.zeros((n-m,m))))
   print(arr)

if n < m:
   x = np.identity(n)
   arr = np.hstack((x,np.zeros((n,m-n))))
   print(arr)
```

The problem arises because `x` is an n*n matrix but `np.zeros((m-n,m))` returns a (m-n)*m matrix which cannot be stacked with `x`. `np.zeros((n,m-n))` returns n*(m-n) matrix which can be stacked with n*n matrix to make a n*m matrix.